# File download using file-saver (angular4 / spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, angular, jwt

i'm working on a project where i need to save PDF file when i click on a button ,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/download/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable String filename) throws IOException{
     String fullPath=FILE_PATH+""+filename+".pdf";
     System.out.println(fullPath);
     File file =new File(fullPath);
     HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
     respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    respHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    respHeaders.add("Accept","application/pdf");
     InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

     return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr,respHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
```

testing it with ARC it shows something like this

[testing my rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0xWQ.png)

and for angular i have for my html

```
<button (click)="saveF(a)">Export</button></div>
```

my component.ts
a="a.pdf";

```
saveF(fileName){

this.authService.saveFile(fileName)
  .subscribe(response=> {
    this.saveToFileSystem(response)
    },
    err=>{
    console.log(err);
      console.log("not ok")
    }
  )
```

}

which call the function

```
private saveToFileSystem(response){
const contentDispositionHeader: string =response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
const parts:string[]=contentDispositionHeader.split('.');
const filename=parts[1].split('=')[1];
const blob =new Blob([response._body]);
saveAs(blob,filename);
```

}

and finally my service

```
saveFile(fileName){if (this.jwtToken== null){
this.loadToken()}
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/download/'+fileName,{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.jwtToken})})}
```

}

and in my browser i get something like this but it doesnt download the file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t7Km.png)

Comment: Can you try to set in the `RequestOptions` of your HttpRequest in the `UrlSearchParams` the `ResponseType` to `Blob`. It seems that the browser is expecting a JSON Response and tries to parse it as JSON

Comment: adding  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/download/' + fileName, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': this.jwtToken}), responseType: 'blob'
    })
  }
} i have now ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

@Daniomi ty for the answer , now it works , i had to add responseType , this is how i change it

```
saveF(fileName) {

this.authService.saveFile(fileName)
  .subscribe(response => {
      const name =fileName;
      const blob = response;
      saveAs(blob,name);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);

      console.log("not ok")
    }
  )
```

}

and in my service

```
saveFile(fileName) {
if (this.jwtToken == null) {
  this.loadToken()
}
// const options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/download/' + fileName, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': this.jwtToken}), responseType: 'blob'
})
```

}